# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message method: 'post', path: '/channels/889108076425281609/messages', code: 50006, httpStatus: 400

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.toLocaleLowerCase() === prefix + 'yardım') {
    const kanal = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTitle('**YARDIM**')
    .addField(':robot::robot: **j!yardım moderasyon = MODERASYON KOMUTLARINI GÖSTERİR**:robot::robot:',"\u200B")
    .addField(':robot::robot:**j!yardım bot = BOT İLE İLGİLİ KOMUTLARI GÖSTERİR**:robot::robot:',"\u200B")
    .addField(':robot::robot:**j!yardım mesaj = MESAJ KOMUTLARINI GÖSTERİR**:robot::robot:',"\u200B")
    .addField(':robot::robot:**j!yakında = YAKINDA GELECEK KOMUTLARI GÖSTERİR**:robot::robot:',"\u200B")
    .addField(':robot::robot:**j!kurallar = KURALLARI GÖSTERİR**:robot::robot:',"\u200B")
    .addField(':robot::robot:**j!gagsure = GAG SÜRELERİNİ GÖSTERİR**:robot::robot:',"\u200B")
    .setTimestamp();
    message.channel.send(kanal).catch(() => {});
  }
})
```

When I try to use the embed message it gives this error and the bot shuts itself down. I am using discord.js v12

Comment: Which version of `discord.js` do you have?

Comment: They sad v12 in the question, hope that helps

Comment: @Ashmedai can you please verify your discord.js version? if it's v12 it shouldn't be throwing errors for the embed send

Answer (score -1):

```js
message.channel.send({ embed: embed });
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
```

One of these 2 options should work with your DJS Version, docs are deprecated so can't help you more if you have more errors